# Curve fitting for a data set to use as a function to 'correct' the deviation from 1

Tags: curve-fitting

So I have a set of data and the 'ideal' situation would be that as the x axis increases (these are the values going from 400 -> 1400) the y axis remains fixed at 1 (this shows that my model isn't under correcting (greater than 1)/ over correcting (less than 1). If I wanted to simply scale my data (I realize this wont be perfect and correct everything exactly to 1) i.e multiply the data points by a specific function, in order to reduce the deviation, such that it changes with x-axis how would I go about doing this?

My data is given below;

x-axis;
1155.62,
1145.45,
1028.93,
1010.53,
1037.17,
1005.32,
936.79,
944.59,
918.11,
881.33,
856.18,
866.1,
709.33,
631.81,
663.3,
594.45,
551.89,
474.52,

y-axis;
1.034777868,
1.015295299,
1.086925252,
1.036980594,
0.978296711,
1.008067083,
1.017656038,
0.989773341,
1.016250776,
1.000408474,
0.995935434,
0.974402494,
0.997589274,
1.071872873,
0.980009046,
1.033627723,
1.015745891,
1.089627413,

To my eye this looks like it would loosely correlate to a parabolic curve - so if I was to use this as a starting point how would I use this function to try and 'pull' the data points towards 1. Really hope someone can offer some guidance.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a forum for programming questions, so ideally you have some code that attempts this fit, and you use a certain language. You may also want to put a figure in your question showing the data with a first attempt at what you want to do.

Comment: What data do you want to scale to 1? The x-data or the y-data? And why? Or simply perform an n-dimensional polynomial fit (if n equals the amount of data, it will be a perfect fit, and you can always scale your y-data to 1; I'm just not sure what's the use for that).

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I effectively want a function that is not too complex (i.e a parabola) that could be multplied by the y data to give approximately 1. The reason why I say approximately 1 is because an n-dimensional polynomial would be very complex and I wouldn't be able to justify that type of curve to the 'physical relevance' of the data. However, parabolic for example I would be able to make a case. What I'm trying to ask is how I would define a function that would approximately make my Y-values 1 when multplied by said function. For example 1.08*(e^kx) = 1.005

Comment: if the data was a (negative - as I assume you would apply the inverse function to try and 'correct' the data) exponential shape  - I forgot to thank you for responding. I'm first trying to understand how I might be able to do this before I fully code it. Sorry If I'm not being very clear at what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem: you know what function you want to use to fit your data, so why don't you go ahead and try? Use something like chi-squared as an estimator how good the fit is.

Comment: Right. So I use the inverse function and multiply this by my Y-value right? this should correct my data point if for example it did fit a parabolic curve. I think I was basically looking for you to validate what I was saying wasn't total nonsense :)

Comment: No, don't use the inverse function. Just *divide* by your best fit function (evaluated at the x-data points).